# Is it possible to have a zipfile in which only some files where encripted/password protected?

Tags: zip, gzip

Would like to create a default project structure, but some business areas of the company do not need to have access to some assets (so I wanna block them).

Is there any way I could create a zipfile and instruct it to use a password when adding some files **and setting a null password** when inserting other files to the same archive.

I am trying to achieve it in unix zip/gzip implementation, under RHEL

Answer (score 2):

You can combine password-protected and non-protected files in a single archive by adding them in separate operations:

```
zip test.zip file1 file2
zip -e test.zip file3 file4
```

will store `file1` and `file2` with no password, and `file3` and `file4` with the password given at the prompt, in `test.zip`.

The unprotected files can be extracted without a password. `unzip` will only request the password if the contents of the protected files need to be retrieved.

This can be also used to store files with different passwords.

Comment: Yes. Zip encrypts the file content, not the archive. Beware it does not encrypt the meta data: filenames, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using the wrong tool for the job... but, if you want to proceed down this path, you could consider a combination of zip and tar to achieve these results. You can password protect the necessary zip files, and not password protect the rest of the zip files, which you then package all in a single tar ball. The archive can be extracted, but the individual zip files/packages can only be expanded with the password(s).

I would however recommend that you start over and rethink on your storage/delivery mechanism to determine a more scaleable and secure method. In this model you are now needing to maintain passwords for each business area (I am assuming here that you are not standardizing passwords across all the 'secure' areas) and once the files are out in the wild are subject to being brute forced since you are allowing access to all the files and relying on the password(s) to protect them. If you know that marketing should never be able to access finance files, why give them access to the files in any format in the first place? Naturally, this is from the outside looking in and with limited details, there may be reasons you are going down the route you have started on.

Comment: Or zip of zip, but I agree: This is probably doing it the wrong way.

Comment: I was not aware of the flexibility of zip that Stephen posts in his answer. So that would seem to be a way to use solely zip if that is the route you decide to proceed with.